# sql query very slow when another table gets fuller

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, but after some time when users start putting in more and more items in the "ci_falsepositives" table, it gets really slow.
The ci_falsepositives table contains a reference field from ci_address_book and another reference field from ci_matched_sanctions.

How can I create a new query but still being able to sort on each field.
For example I can still sort on "hits" or "matches"

```
SELECT *, matches - falsepositives AS hits
  FROM (SELECT c.*, IFNULL(p.total, 0) AS matches, 
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM ci_falsepositives n 
                 WHERE n.addressbook_id = c.reference
                   AND n.sanction_key IN 
                       (SELECT sanction_key FROM ci_matched_sanctions)
               ) AS falsepositives 
          FROM ci_address_book c 
          LEFT JOIN 
               (SELECT addressbook_id, COUNT(match_id) AS total 
                  FROM ci_matched_sanctions
                 GROUP BY addressbook_id) AS p 
            ON c.id = p.addressbook_id
       ) S
 ORDER BY folder asc, wholename ASC
 LIMIT 0,15
```

Comment: Have you thought about adding some indeces?

Comment: each table has an id field which is a primary index

Comment: **What** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... and performance-related stuff like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: mysql - myisam (I have also tried innodb, without difference, innodb being slightly slower)

Comment: execution plan? table schema ?

Comment: If you really want to solve this problem - let us to know schema of your tables

Comment: -1 for asking for query optimisation help without including table structures, indexes or query plans. (Or, originally, even the relevant RDBMS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to be the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ci_falsepositives` sub-query. That sub-query can be written using an inner join between `ci_falsepositives` and `ci_matched_sanctions`, but the optimizer might do that for you anyway. What I think you need to do, though, is make that sub-query into a separate query in the FROM clause of the 'next query out' (that is, `SELECT c.*, ...`). Probably, that query is being evaluated multiple times - and that's what's hurting you when people add records to `ci_falsepositives`. You should study the query plan carefully.

Maybe this query will be better:

```
SELECT *, matches - falsepositives AS hits
  FROM (SELECT c.*, IFNULL(p.total, 0) AS matches, f.falsepositives
          FROM ci_address_book AS c
          JOIN (SELECT n.addressbook_id, COUNT(*) AS falsepositives
                  FROM ci_falsepositives    AS n
                  JOIN ci_matched_sanctions AS m
                    ON n.sanction_key = m.sanction_key
                 GROUP BY n.addressbook_id
               ) AS f
            ON c.reference = f.addressbook_id
          LEFT JOIN 
               (SELECT addressbook_id, COUNT(match_id) AS total 
                  FROM ci_matched_sanctions
                 GROUP BY addressbook_id) AS p 
            ON c.id = p.addressbook_id
       ) AS s
 ORDER BY folder asc, wholename ASC
 LIMIT 0, 15
```

Comment: this doesn't work anymore... when sorting on another field (example matches or hits) my results are gone. I only get a few results instead of everything. Also it seems like the number calculation is gone.. I get "falsepositives" which aren't in the table. It says for 1 I have 93, but there are none.

Comment: I don't have a strong enough grasp on your schema, or sample data to work with.  You've got three tables for which you've not really given us the schema - where the foreign keys are particularly crucial.  It may be that I've completely misunderstood the original query.  The general idea is valid - that the detailed SQL is not correct does not altogether surprise me.

Comment: **To debug it**: (1) test the sub-query ending `AS f` in isolation and ensure it produces sensible answers; (2) validate the join between `AS c` and `AS f`.  I'm not clear why one join connects `c.id` with `p.addressbook_id` while the other joins `c.references` with `n.addressbook_id` in your original query.

Comment: thank you, I will try that. If I still can't figure it out, I will add the schema to the original question.